# Finding final value of sum from double summation code fragment.

Tags: summation, computer-science

```
sum = 0; inc = 0
for i from 1 to n
for j from 1 to i  
sum = sum + inc
inc = inc + 1
```

What does it mean when it is asking the "final value of sum" from above code fragment. Can someone give me some hints so that I can work on this exercise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code in the original question is ambiguous. Do you intend for the last two statements both to be in the inner loop? It will definitely affect your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means to find the value of 'sum' after the for loops have been executed.

EDIT: The following assumes both of the last code pieces are inside the inner loop.

First we find the number of times sum+inc is executed. This is

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^i1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Define $\mathrm{Inc}(k)$ as the value of inc in the $k$-th execution of sum+inc. Then

$$\mathrm{FinalSum}=\sum_{k=1}^{n(n+1)/2}\mathrm{Inc}(k)$$

For each time sum+inc is executed is executed, inc increases by $1$ and it starts at $0$, but we only increment inc after we have added it to sum, so $\mathrm{Inc}(k)=k-1$. Hence
$$\begin{align}\mathrm{FinalSum}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n(n+1)/2}\mathrm{Inc}(k)
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{n(n+1)/2}k-1
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n(n+1)/2-1}k
\\&=\frac{(n(n+1)/2-1)(n(n+1)/2)}{2}
\\&=\frac{1}{8}\left(n(n+1)-2\right)\left(n(n+1)\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{8}n(n+1)(n^2+n-2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge. I was never thinking inc(k)= k-1. Everything makes perfectly clear now. Thanks.

Comment: @Rocky Glad to help!